# Visual Studio Async CTP - Working with ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

The new Async framework released today at PDC10 looks really brilliant.

I've had quite a bit of experience working with asynchronous applications/services and can say from experience that it is amazingly how simplified they have made the process.

My question is - will this play well with ASP.net MVC asynchronous controllers?

If it doesn't - I hope the MVC team can migrate to this async pattern

Comment: Okay random down vote and close vote...  any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated during Anders Hejlsberg's PDC 2010 session converting existing async implementations to use the new `async` and `await` keywords is quite straightforward. We (the MVC team) will have more guidance about that in the future.